# vscode highlight overridden mixin methods in a python class definition?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a class `Class FOO(MixinOne,...)` which inherits from mixins but also overrides some of the methods from those mixins.  Is there a way to easily highlight those overridden methods in vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, vscode does not have this feature, but the **OUTLINE** view on the left might work for you.

[image]

As for highlighting the overridden method, I submitted a request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19984).